# Conditionally extracting multiple substrings and returning a value for each substring using a for-loop

Tags: r

I'd like to find an elegant approach to:

1. Use a for-loop each unique element in 'zone'
2. to extract multiple substrings from 'country_name' each row in df1
3. store the multiple substrings for each zone/row as a vector or list for the next step
4. return a value for each zone/row vector in df1 for the unique element the substring belongs to by using df2.
5. Resulting output will look like df3

I have two dataframes:

The first data.frame:

```
zone = c("A", "B", "C")
country_name = c("Canada and UK", "UK and USA", "USA and Canada and UK") 
df1 = data.frame(zone, country_name)
```

The second data.frame:

```
zone_area = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
country_name = c("Canada", "UK", "USA", "Canada", "UK", "USA", "Canada", "UK", "USA")
cost = c(4, 8, 6, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5)
df2 = data.frame(zone_area, country_name, cost)
```

The *final resulting data.frame should* looks like df3:

```
zone = c("A", "B", "C")
country_name = c("Canada and UK", "UK and USA", "USA and Canada and UK")
cost = c(12, 15, 20)
df3 = data.frame(zone, country_name, cost)
```

The reason why I need to use a for-loop is because the code should work if different values of zone are used.

Thank you to everyone that views this question and can provide a method to work on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could a `left_join` after splitting the 'country_name' by 'and', grouped by 'zone', get the `sum` of 'cost' and do a `right_join` with the original dataset to get the expected output

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   separate_rows(country_name, sep="\\s+and\\s+") %>%
   left_join(df2) %>% 
   group_by(zone) %>% 
   summarise(cost = sum(cost)) %>% 
   right_join(df1) %>%
   select(zone, country_name, cost)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  zone  country_name           cost
#   <fct> <fct>                 <dbl>
#1 A     Canada and UK            12
#2 B     UK and USA               15
#3 C     USA and Canada and UK    20
```

---

Or instead of using `separate_rows`, we do a `left_join` and then `filter` based on the pattern in 'country_name', get the `sum` of 'cost' and `right_join` with 'df1'

```
left_join(df2, df1, by = "zone") %>%
    group_by(zone) %>% 
    filter(grepl(gsub("\\s*and\\s*", "|", country_name.y[1]), country_name.x)) %>%
    summarise(cost = sum(cost)) %>%
    right_join(df1)
```

Comment: I prefer the second suggested method, it allows for grepl in the scenario that i need to filter on longer strings. But both suggests work equally well!